# How does a layperson know whether to hire a Queen's Counsel?

Tags: england-and-wales, silks, barristers

1. A layperson may not know whether his/her case is complex enough to hire a Queen's Counsel. So how does a layperson decide, when deciding hiring a public access  barrister?

2. Are barristers obligated to advise a client on such a question? To wit, will a Junior Counsel truly choose to lose business, by tell a prospective client to hire a QC instead? And vice versa? Barristers may not be the most scrupulous humans (insert chiding joke about lawyers here).

Comment: What does your solicitor advise?

Comment: @Calchas I don't have one. I ask the above in general, and not for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, the client will be hiring the barrister based on the advice of their solicitor; who is definitely not a lay person. That said:

1. How do you, as a lay person, decide if your medical condition is serious enough to require a professor or an intern? Similarly, how experienced does your engineer or architect need to be? The answer is the same in all situations - you balance the extra expense with your assessment of the expected outcome.
2. Most professionals genuinely have the best interests of their client in mind because:

   1. Most are genuinely ethical - consultants like barristers more than most because they are not beholden to an employer.
   2. Its bad for business if it is not. Reputation is *everything*; consistently take on cases that you can't win or over-service your clients and word gets around.
   3. Barristers are officers of the court - they need to work with the judges on a regular basis and nothing pisses off a judge more than a barrister who doesn't know the relevant law.
   4. What makes you think *any* barrister is short of work? Most will happily pass over a client they can't service properly because there are a dozen more lining up.

Answer (score 3):

For question 2, there is a firm requirement on barristers to inform the client if different counsel would be called for. To quote the Bar Standards Board handbook:

> **rC17**
>   Your duty to act in the best interests of each 
>   client (CD2) includes a duty to consider whether the 
>   client’s
>    best interests are served by different legal representation, and if so, to advise the 
>   client
>    to that 
>   effect.

The guidance specifically mentions that if something should be handled by more (or less) experienced counsel, there is an ethical duty to tell their client.